# What URI should I enter to run my Web API2?

Tags: c#, controller, routes, asp.net-web-api2

What URI should I enter to run my Web API 2 rating route?

I have tried the following URIs with POST method and I get 404 errors:

```
http://localhost:52229/PersonalAutoAPI/RunRating
```

This one works (different controller):

```
http://localhost:52229/PersonalAutoAPI/Drivers
```

I can GET my driver API

Here is my webapiconfig.config.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PersonalAuto
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "PersonalAutoAPI",
               routeTemplate: "PersonalAutoAPI/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );


            var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is my `RatingControler.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using PersonalAuto.Models;

namespace PersonalAuto.Controllers
{
    public class RatingControler : ApiController

    {
        public IEnumerable<RatingResult>  PostRunRaing([FromBody] RatingInfo MyRateInfo)
        {
            RatingResult[] myRatingResult =
               {new RatingResult{PremiumDP = 0M,PremiumEFTDownPament = 0M,PremiumMontlyPayment = 0M,PremiumEFTMonthlyPayment=0M,PremiumPIF=0M }
            };
            return myRatingResult;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult PostRunRating([FromBody] RatingInfo MyRateInfo)
        {
            RatingResult MyRating = new RatingResult { PremiumDP = 0M, PremiumEFTDownPament = 0M, PremiumMontlyPayment = 0M, PremiumEFTMonthlyPayment = 0M, PremiumPIF = 0M };


            if (MyRating == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            return Ok(MyRating);

        }
    }
}
```

Here it is my diverscontroler.cs (this works with above uri)

```
using PersonalAuto.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;

namespace PersonalAuto.Controllers
{
    public class DriversController : ApiController
    {

        public IEnumerable<Driver> GetAllDrivers()
        {
            Driver[] myDriverArray =
               {
                    new Driver { id = "1234", first_name = "eric", last_name = "last", dl_number = "1234", address_1 = "1234 test st", address_2 = "", city = "dallas", state = "TX", zip = "75248", mobile = "214-415-9224" }
            };
            return myDriverArray;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetDriverByLicenseNo(string drivers_license_number, string drivers_license_state)
        {
            string PreToken = "xxxxx:xxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PreToken));

            if (drivers_license_state == null)
                drivers_license_state = "TX";
            var driver = new Driver { id = Token, first_name = "eric", last_name = "last", dl_number = "1234", address_1 = "1234 test st", address_2 = "", city = "dallas", state = "TX", zip = "75248", mobile = "214-415-9224" };  // products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (driver == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(driver);

        }

    }
}
```

I have been pulling my hair out over this!  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your controller is called `Rating` and not `RunRating`, the correct URI is `http://localhost:52229/PersonalAutoAPI/Rating`. Also be aware that you have currently two action methods that maps to the same route `PostRunRaing` and `PostRunRating`, you need change the route of one of them if you want to keep both inside the same controller.

Comment: The routing setup depends on the controller class name ending in `Controller`.  In your sample code, you have it misspelled: `RatingControler` should be `RatingController`

Answer (score 0):

The routing setup depends on the controller class name ending in Controller. In your sample code, you have it misspelled: `RatingControler` should be `RatingController`

Also check the spelling of `PostRunRaing` - which seems like it should be `PostRunRating`, (but it can't be because then you would have a naming conflict.  The controller wouldn't know whether to return an IEnumerable or an IHttpActionResult.)

Fix that, and then I think your route will be:

http://localhost:52229/PersonalAutoAPI/Rating/PostRunRating

Answer (score 0):

There code has two problem:

1. Change RatingControler  to RatingController. The controller factory doesn't recognize RatingControler because it expects *Controller.
2. you cannot have two method with same http verb and method name. you can not overload methods in controllers.